# How to get volume indexes using power shell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to get volume indexes on my computer.

An example:

If we do list volume,below is the output:

```
 Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
 ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
 Volume 0     D                       CD-ROM          0 B  No Media
 Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    350 MB  Healthy    System
 Volume 2     C                NTFS   Partition     39 GB  Healthy    Boot
 Volume 3     I   software  NTFS   Partition     17 GB  Healthy
```

the volume indexes are `0,1,2,3`

Can I get these indexes using Power shell commands, instead of parsing the output of list volume command?

Comment: What command are you using to get that result?

Comment: I guess he is using `diskpart.exe` and `list Volume`.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh probably true (based on `list volume`). It should have been part of the question.

Comment: Does the answer help?  If yes please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably searching for this snippet:

`Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object Index`

Gets you the Index for all drives.

If you would like to differenciate among the drives you can easily get other info like:
`Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object model,name, index`

All available properties to the `Win32_DiskDrive` class are:

```
  TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_DiskDrive

Name                        MemberType    Definition
----                        ----------    ----------
PSComputerName              AliasProperty PSComputerName = __SERVER
Reset                       Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Reset()
SetPowerState               Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject SetPowerState(System.UInt16 PowerState, Syste... Availability                Property      uint16 Availability {get;set;}
BytesPerSector              Property      uint32 BytesPerSector {get;set;}
Capabilities                Property      uint16[] Capabilities {get;set;}
CapabilityDescriptions      Property      string[] CapabilityDescriptions {get;set;}
Caption                     Property      string Caption {get;set;}
CompressionMethod           Property      string CompressionMethod {get;set;}
ConfigManagerErrorCode      Property      uint32 ConfigManagerErrorCode {get;set;}
ConfigManagerUserConfig     Property      bool ConfigManagerUserConfig {get;set;}
CreationClassName           Property      string CreationClassName {get;set;}
DefaultBlockSize            Property      uint64 DefaultBlockSize {get;set;}
Description                 Property      string Description {get;set;}
DeviceID                    Property      string DeviceID {get;set;}
ErrorCleared                Property      bool ErrorCleared {get;set;}
ErrorDescription            Property      string ErrorDescription {get;set;}
ErrorMethodology            Property      string ErrorMethodology {get;set;}
FirmwareRevision            Property      string FirmwareRevision {get;set;}
Index                       Property      uint32 Index {get;set;}
InstallDate                 Property      string InstallDate {get;set;}
InterfaceType               Property      string InterfaceType {get;set;}
LastErrorCode               Property      uint32 LastErrorCode {get;set;}
Manufacturer                Property      string Manufacturer {get;set;}
MaxBlockSize                Property      uint64 MaxBlockSize {get;set;}
MaxMediaSize                Property      uint64 MaxMediaSize {get;set;}
MediaLoaded                 Property      bool MediaLoaded {get;set;}
MediaType                   Property      string MediaType {get;set;}
MinBlockSize                Property      uint64 MinBlockSize {get;set;}
Model                       Property      string Model {get;set;}
Name                        Property      string Name {get;set;}
NeedsCleaning               Property      bool NeedsCleaning {get;set;}
NumberOfMediaSupported      Property      uint32 NumberOfMediaSupported {get;set;}
Partitions                  Property      uint32 Partitions {get;set;}
PNPDeviceID                 Property      string PNPDeviceID {get;set;}
PowerManagementCapabilities Property      uint16[] PowerManagementCapabilities {get;set;}
PowerManagementSupported    Property      bool PowerManagementSupported {get;set;}
SCSIBus                     Property      uint32 SCSIBus {get;set;}
SCSILogicalUnit             Property      uint16 SCSILogicalUnit {get;set;}
SCSIPort                    Property      uint16 SCSIPort {get;set;}
SCSITargetId                Property      uint16 SCSITargetId {get;set;}
SectorsPerTrack             Property      uint32 SectorsPerTrack {get;set;}
SerialNumber                Property      string SerialNumber {get;set;}
Signature                   Property      uint32 Signature {get;set;}
Size                        Property      uint64 Size {get;set;}
Status                      Property      string Status {get;set;}
StatusInfo                  Property      uint16 StatusInfo {get;set;}
SystemCreationClassName     Property      string SystemCreationClassName {get;set;}
SystemName                  Property      string SystemName {get;set;}
TotalCylinders              Property      uint64 TotalCylinders {get;set;}
TotalHeads                  Property      uint32 TotalHeads {get;set;}
TotalSectors                Property      uint64 TotalSectors {get;set;}
TotalTracks                 Property      uint64 TotalTracks {get;set;}
TracksPerCylinder           Property      uint32 TracksPerCylinder {get;set;}
```